# Regarding two way binding in an input field in CORE-UI Angular

Tags: angular, core-ui

I m using CORE-UI angular for my project. I got stuck with an issue while doing two-way binding with an input. the problem is whenever I specify two way binding in an input field it appears to be valid by default and apply ng-valid class. I extremely need help to get rid of this issue

***Before applying two way binding in an input***

**code**

```
<form
  #loginForm="ngForm"
  cForm
  autocomplete="off"
  (ngSubmit)="login()">

  <h1>Login</h1>
  <p class="text-medium-emphasis">Sign In to your account</p>
  <c-input-group class="mb-3">
    <span cInputGroupText>
        <svg
            cIcon
            name="cilUser"
        ></svg>
    </span>
    <input
        cFormControl
        type="text"
        placeholder="Username"
        name="UserName"
    >
  </c-input-group>
</form>
```

[image]

***After applying Two way binding***
**code**

```
 <form
  #loginForm="ngForm"
  cForm
  autocomplete="off"
  (ngSubmit)="login()">

  <h1>Login</h1>
  <p class="text-medium-emphasis">Sign In to your account</p>
  <c-input-group class="mb-3">
    <span cInputGroupText>
        <svg
            cIcon
            name="cilUser"
        ></svg>
    </span>
    <input
        cFormControl
        type="text"
        placeholder="Username"
        name="UserName"
        [(ngModel)]="model.UserName" <!-- here --!>
    >
  </c-input-group>
</form>
```

[image]

**ng valid class rendered by default**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This syntax
`[(ngModel)]="model.UserName"`
is two-way binding. If you only want one-way, then use either

```
[ngModel]="model.UserName"
```

OR

```
(ngModel)="model.UserName"
```